# bot doesn't collect the messages ASAP

Tags: discord.js

I'm making an application with Discord.js. Everything's working fine, however the bot does not collect the messages as soon as all the questions have been answered.
It does when the collector runs out of time.

How can I trigger `collector.on('end' ...)` once all of the questions have been answered?

```
 const questions =[
        'First Name:',
        'Last Name:',
        'How old are you:',
        'Your email:',
        'What is your time zone:',
        'Where are you from:',
        'What languages are you speaking:',
        'Have your ever been punished on our server:',
        'On which server your most active on:',
        'Have you ever been in a staff team:',
        'Tell us about your self:'
]

let counter = 0
    
const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
    
const collector = message.author.dmChannel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
   max: questions.Lenght,
   time: 60000                     
});
       
message.author.send(questions[counter++]);

console.log(`1st question has been sent to ${message.author.tag}`);

collector.on('collect', (m) => {
   if(counter < questions.length) {
      console.log(`sending more questions to ${message.author.tag} until answer them all`);
      message.author.send(questions[counter++])   
   }
})

collector.on('end', (collected) => {
   console.log(`collected ${collected.size} messages`);

   message.author.send(`Your application has been successfully sent`);
   let counter = 0
   collected.forEach((value) => {
      console.log(questions[counter++], value.content)    
   })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `max: questions.Lenght` instead of `max: questions.length` with a lower `L` and `th`